# Android custom button with text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I'm trying to make a button that looks like the 4 buttons on top when you open the play store. (Apps, music, books, movies)  A button with an image on the left and on the right you have text that is properly aligned with the image. By that I mean the text is not centered. I've been trying with following code but it's not the result that I'm looking for.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/contact_website"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/website"
        android:drawablePadding="-20sp"
        android:onClick="website_onClick"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:text="@string/contact_link"/>
```

Anyone out there that can help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove -ve padding .

Try this

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#123456"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:drawablePadding="0sp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="Button Text"
            android:padding="10dp"
         >
        </Button>
```

This worked for me